# problemas al ejecutar Shell en PHP

Tags: php, shell, iis

Buen día, una pregunta hace unos días tenia montado un servidor apache en windows R mi apache era XAMPP y todo funcionaba bien, pero lo migre a IIS y tengo un problema, básicamente tengo un comando que revisa si el servicio "php.exe" de xampp ahora en la ruta de IIS osea "PHP\php.exe", se esta ejecutando, ocupo un archivo .ini para obtener la ruta de mi servicio php y la ruta del php del server, la razón es que estoy haciendo un socket para poder ejecutar en el servidor, bueno el problema es que no ejecuta el comando en shell y la pagina se queda recargando, utilizo la clase "COM" y ya esta habilitado en php.ini

Tengo la sospecha de que es algún tema de configuración pues en mi XAMPP local si funciona pero en IIS no, adjunto los códigos relacionados

header.php (se ejecuta en cualquier parte de mi sitio para comprobar si el servicio se ejecuta)

```
try {
    $var = exec('tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq php.exe"');
    if (!preg_match('/^php.exe\s+(\d+)/i', $var)) {
        $file = './ws/furd.ini';
        $setdb = parse_ini_file($file, TRUE);
        $WshShell = new COM("WScript.Shell");
        $oExec = $WshShell->Run($setdb['passion']['php_path'].'php.exe -f "'.$setdb['passion']['ws_path'].'server.php"', 0, false);
        header("Refresh:2");
    }
} catch(Exception $e) {
echo "Error al ejecutar Shell";}
```

furd.ini

```
[local]
php_path = C:\xampp\php\
ws_path  = C:\xampp\htdocs\ws\
version  = 1.1.2
[passion]
php_path = C:\PHP\
ws_path  = C:\inetpub\wwwroot\ws\
```

El que me interesa es la ruta de passion

y pues basicamente el comando que requiero ejecutar, SOLO SI ES QUE NO SE ESTA EJECUTANDO YA es el siguiente:

```
C:\PHP\php.exe -f C:\inetpub\wwwroot\ws\server.php
```

Agradezco su apoyo compañeros

Answer (score 0):

Listo, El problema no era el codigo, el problema estaba en el archivo "php.exe" del apache
me generaba un error al intentarlo ejectar directo en consola, solucion, reinstalar la version de php que estoy usando o en su defecto, reemplazar el archivo php.exe por el de xampp que era el que me funcionaba